# Journal of serious opinions on weighty matters for mathematicians

Tags: reference-request, soft-question, ho.history-overview, mathematical-philosophy, journals

Is there any scholarly journal

- of **opinion** on professional matters,
- for mathematicians, that would *exclude* things just as relevant to other fields as to mathematics,
- that is *not* just $\text{“}\,$leisure reading$\text{,''}$ (i.e., it is on weighty consequential matters)?

"Professional matters" would include research, philosophy, and pedagogy, and probably other things.

Comment: I don't know any journal that is *exclusively* opinion, but many publications often print such opinion pieces, e.g. *AMS Notices*.

Comment: I posted this on m.s.e. without getting any replies: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3574020/journal-of-serious-opinions-on-weighty-matters-for-mathematicians

Comment: @NateEldredge :  "Many" is an interesting word.

Comment: and let me guess, you want it not to degrade to Blue-Red mudslinging in a few issues? ;)

Comment: Another journal that may interest you is [*Journal of Humanistic Mathematics*](https://scholarship.claremont.edu/jhm/).

Comment: Are you exclusively interested in journals in English language? (A lot of non-native speakers easily write mathematical papers, but would have a hard time writing a well-written text with opinions etc.)

Comment: @YCor : Not necessarily. $\qquad$

Comment: @darijgrinberg : Anyone who disagrees with me about which versions of the Axiom of Choice should be allowed in a certain narrow area of research is a vile Nazi!! $${}$$ yeah, I guess exculding that sort of material would be nice. Or would be required.

Comment: The post to mathstack was deleted a few years ago.

Answer (score 5):

This question was asked some time ago but remains on the unanswered queue. I want to echo [Nate's comment](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/354719/journal-of-serious-opinions-on-weighty-matters-for-mathematicians#comment889913_354719) regarding the Journal of Humanistic Mathematics. I've published two papers there. The [first one](https://scholarship.claremont.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?referer=https://www.google.com/&httpsredir=1&article=1291&context=jhm) included plenty of "serious opinions on weighty matters" such as the balance between writing research papers concisely vs welcoming new mathematicians into the field, and our collective habit of obfuscating the thought process that led to a result, leading to the impression that doing math successfully requires an inexplicable stroke of genius. We also opined on the importance of finding ways to share mental imagery with readers/listeners, and finding ways to explain math research to the general public. [The second paper](https://scholarship.claremont.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1666&context=jhm) included opinions (and data from surveys) about many topics, like the importance of play as part of the research process, the value of expository writing, the importance of sharing personal hardships so that junior people know it's possible to bounce back from setbacks and still have a productive professional career (I have [done this myself](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/463813/how-to-write-mathematics-without-typing/463818#463818) a [few times](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/433686/math-papers-where-the-only-issue-is-that-someone-else-couldve-done-it-but-didn/433691#433691)), improving upon the culture of spreading knowledge via word-of-mouth (especially with an eye towards making math more inclusive, including to people who can't easily attend conferences), and more.

I'm a big fan of the Journal of Humanistic Mathematics and would love to see more people submitting articles there. They certainly seem to welcome (well thought-out, potentially research driven) opinions on matters that many mathematicians care about.